# Get Width Of An Element Inside A Dumb React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to know the width of an element in react dumb component.

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

const Message = ({ ...props }) => (
   <article>
     <section> <!-- This is the element I want to find width of -->
       <h2>{name}</h2>
       <p>{description}</p>
     </section>
     <p>{moment(created_at).format("h:mm a")}</p>
   </article>
);
export default Message;
```

I want to find the width of the `section` element, so that I can do some UI changes based on that width. The thing to note here is that this `Message` component is being mapped in an array. And for every `Message` component that get's rendered I want to find the width of the `section` element in each of that component.

I did some research and I found an implementation in a smart component which was like this.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.myInput.offsetWidth)
  }

  render () {
    <div ref={input => {this.myInput = input}}>some elem</div>
  }
}
```

Can I do similar like this but without using `this` or without using `state`, just plain old vanilla JavaScript.

Any kind of help or direction would be highly appreciated, Cheers :)

Comment: No that I know of unless you do it in a parent component. If you have to read layout info from the DOM (which sometimes we have to in React, for things like resizable split panes), then you need component lifecycle hooks to read from the DOM after mount

Comment: Is there a way off assigning a unique UUID as an id to each of those elements and then use vanilla JavaScript to get each element's width. Is it an optimal approach performance wise?

Comment: As far as I know you have to do something like mount component > in didmount read from dom > broadcast new change (either state or to parent prop callback) > do whatever with new information from DOM, probably a second render. Since you have to do 2 renders, there's no benefit to using vanilla javacript. Just use refs and pass the size data the normal react way

Comment: This just has a code smell to it, I believe we can come up with a better approach. Still thinking on it lol.

Comment: I've thought on it for a while, if you have a good answer you should answer my question as well :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864038/react-how-to-read-from-the-dom-after-mount

Comment: I'll think on it, and try to come up with something if I can. :)